# Working with isometric refrence images

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image

How does one set up the camera for working with isometric reference images? I have tried addons like BLAM and others, but those require either vanishing points, or non-parallel lines. An example image for what I want to use is attached. Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 6):

Under the assumption of right angles somewhere in the structure you can rotate a cube to match the angles on the picture and work from there. You should make yourself familiar with the "local" axis of an object.

[image: rotated cube]
[image]